# Unity Cloud Build - Android - Shader error on build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, cloud, shader

First time I made "Unity Cloud Build" build my project for Android, I got the following error:

> Player export failed. Reason: Shader error in 'Sprites/Default': Internal error communicating with the shader compiler process

I have no idea what that means. I don't have any custom shaders, and I've followed the tutorials for building to Android on my PC, but Unity Cloud Build throws this at me.

> **EDIT:** I since found that **others had had similar problems, but not identical errors**, with their first builds to different platforms.

I looked high and low for an answer for about an hour, and couldn't find any.

**I did find the answer, though! See below.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply made it build for Android a second time, and everything worked! :)

I since found that others had had similar problems, but not identical errors, with their first builds to different platforms.

So, if it was your first time building to the platform in question, try building for it again, before panicking.

Comment: Fixed, I'll removed my comments, to cleanup this question